# How to send map long and lat with more details to firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-maps

In this code, I need to send **name** and **number** to the location database with the map's long and lat. Marker's long and lat sending to the firebase without any issue but name and number not sending to the firebase. I cannot find the issue of the code because in the logcat there are not showing any issue. Can you please help me to fix this.

```
package com.example.policeemergencysystem;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.policeemergencysystem.Prevelant.Prevelant;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.policeemergencysystem.Model.AdminOrders;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStates;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.example.policeemergencysystem.Prevelant.Prevelant;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{


    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Button doneBtn;
    TextView backBtn;
    Marker myMarker;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private String name;
    private String userID = "", userNAME = "", userPHONE = "";
    DatabaseReference ordersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Location")
            .child(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getUsername());


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        doneBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneBtn);
        backBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
        userID = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
        userNAME = getIntent().getStringExtra("uname");
        userPHONE = getIntent().getStringExtra("uphone");




        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new
                LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task= LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
                try {
                    LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.

                } catch (ApiException exception) {
                    switch (exception.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                            // user a dialog.
                            try {
                                // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                                        MapsActivity.this,
                                        101);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                                // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                            // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        //Check whether the network provider is enabled
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    //Get the Latitude
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    //Get the Longitude
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    //Instantiate the class, LatLng
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    //Instantiate the class, GeoCoder
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());

                    try {
                        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                        String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality()+",";
                        str += addressList.get(0).getCountryName()+",";
                        str += addressList.get(0).getPostalCode();
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 14.0f));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            });
        }
        else if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    //Get the Latitude
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    //Get the Longitude
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    //Instantiate the class, LatLng
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                    String name = new String(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getUsername());
                    //Instantiate the class, GeoCoder
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());

                    try {
                        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                        String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality()+",";
                        str += addressList.get(0).getCountryName()+",";
                        str += addressList.get(0).getPostalCode();
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(latLng)
                                .zoom(17).build();
                        //Zoom in and animate the camera.
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 101:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        // All required changes were successfully made
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,states.isLocationPresent()+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Canceled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please be patience until we find your current location...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

                // First check if myMarker is null
                if (myMarker == null) {

                    // Marker was not set yet. Add marker:
                    myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latLng)
                            .title("Accidnet Location")
                            .snippet("Put the marker to your accident location")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

                    doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Your location has been placed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            HashMap<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                            DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Location").child(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getUsername());
                            myRef.child("name").setValue(userNAME);
                            myRef.child("phone").setValue(userPHONE);
                            myRef.child(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getUsername()).updateChildren(userMap);

                          finish();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                          startActivity(intent);



                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    // Marker already exists, just update it's position
                    myMarker.setPosition(latLng);
                    LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(myMarker.getPosition().latitude, myMarker.getPosition().longitude);
                }
                HashMap<String, Object> adminMap = new HashMap<>();
                DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Location").child(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getUsername());
                LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(myMarker.getPosition().latitude, myMarker.getPosition().longitude);
                myRef.child("latitude").setValue(myLatLng.latitude);
                myRef.child("longitude").setValue(myLatLng.longitude);
                myRef.child(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getUsername()).updateChildren(adminMap);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Please minimize the code.

Comment: Make sure that you read the [Google Maps Terms of Service particularly 3.2.3 (a)(b)](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3.-license.) before saving data from the Maps API as it might be in violation of these terms.